# How can I save multiple SVGs in one file and use one of them depending on a condition?

Tags: html, angular, svg

I'm using angular, and the question is, if I put all my SVGs in one file, can I dynamically put them in the HTML code depending on a condition? It has to be SVGs because I need to use the fill option dynamically too.

I can just use *ngIf but with the long SVG codes, it becomes unreadable. Is there a viable solution? Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate more what u mean by"unreadable"? what stops you to place all 3 svgs  into one HTML\ts\scss component with condition bound via @Input?

Comment: this link can be usefull: https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/using-an-svg-sprite-icon-system-in-angular-9d4056357b60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I solved this in angular. I made separate components for each svg. Then pass value for stroke and fill to those components, and use the value to assign class.

So basically, I get the value X from backend, that values gets passed to the component, and that is switched around conditionally.

```
<app-example-svg [fill]="fill" [stroke]="stroke"  *ngIf="type === 1"> </app-example-svg>
```

Now this value decides, which svg is used.

2nd, I use these values to change the classes applied.

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this.changeColor(this.fill, this.stroke);
  }
  changeColor(fill, stroke) {
    if (stroke) $('.svg').addClass(`stroke${stroke}`);
    if (fill) $('.svg').addClass(`fill${fill}`);
  }
```

And I get dynamically switching SVGs, with dynamic switching of fill and stroke properties.

Thanks to everyone who replied!